# Why is select_on_container_copy_construction needed?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, c++17

For allocators why is `select_on_container_copy_construction` needed opposed to just overloading the copy-constructor?

Are there instances when we want to define two seperate copy-construction implementations depending on if we are copying the actual allocator vs container?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(The trait you're referring to is actually called [`select_on_container_copy_construction`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/select_on_container_copy_construction).)

The copy constructors of standard library containers *are* in fact overloaded and provide an allocator-extended version:

```
A a1 = f(), a2 = g();  // allocators

std::vector<int, A> v1(a1);
std::vector<int, A> v2(v1, a2);  // allocator-extended copy
std::vector<int, A> v3 = v1;     // regular copy, uses select_on_container_copy_construction
```

However, using an overload is not always an option, and generally allocator-aware containers should be usable just as easily and seamlessly as if you weren't aware of the allocator choices. That means that certain decisions, such as how to allocate a copy of a container, may need to be customizable directly via the allocator type, and not via the user's type.

For example, you could imagine a situation where the contents of one vector all go onto one (possibly growable) arena, but when you make a new vector, you'd like that to go onto a new, separate arena, and generic code should not need to have to know about this.

Whether this library feature is useful in practice is a separate question, but hopefully this shows why this part design has some motivation.

Comment: That took me a couple of reads to finally parse it together. 
Interested in seeing any real world examples if you have any. Thanks

Comment: @JosephFranciscus: I don't know any "common" allocators for which `select_on_container_copy_construction` wouldn't do anything other than returning a copy of the current allocator off-hand, but what I wrote in the answer could be a plausible design. Consider also that the trait might return a copy _and_ also perform some other action, e.g. inform some global memory manager that a copy has occurred, etc.

Comment: @KerrekSB std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator uses select_on_container_copy_construction to generate pmr allocator with default memory resource on copy rather than propagate existing memory resource.